# WebBrower additional headers

Tags: c#

I am using WebBrowser control to send post data. There is overloaded Navigate method

```
public void Navigate(
string urlString,
string targetFrameName,
byte[] postData,
string additionalHeaders
)
```

How to format additionalHeaders string so I could specify 2 headers: referer and content-type

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nReferer: http://foo.com\r\n"
```